# What does the "Remove" option do in Visual Studio Installer, after pausing an update?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, ide, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-installer

I am facing a very serious issue to my normally running Visual Studio 2022. I pressed the "Update" button and because of an internet connectivity issue, I pressed the "Pause" button.

Because of this, whenever I start Visual Studio 2022, I get the following error message:

[image: Visual Studio 2022 won't start up]

Now when I open the Visual Studio 2022 Installer application, I am puzzled by the "Remove" option when I click "More". I do not want to update Visual Studio because I need to do some,
urgent software work at the present moment.

[image: Confusing 'Remove' option]

My question is does clicking "Remove" undo everything and return back to the state before I hit the "Update" button? Does "Remove" mean uninstall Visual Studio 2022 (which I do not want to do)?

The Visual Studio 2022, that was working fine had .NET as well and it would be very difficult to uninstall and re-install it.

I am feeling really lost, and that's why I am intending to ask it here.

Please note, that I had to "Pause" the update because of a persistent internet connection failure, while downloading large files and I never clicked the "Resume" button, because I do not want to continue with the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this with my old Visual Studio 2019 installation.  I started an update for it, paused it, and then tried the "Remove" action and was prompted with this:

[image]

I clicked the Ok button, and it began to uninstall.  So yes - the Remove option will perform an uninstall.